# How to initialise Mat data structure multiple times in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

The following will create 1 particle of Mat data structure and initialise it,

```
static Mat Particle = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But how to create 100 such particles and initialise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (assuming you want them all initialised the same?) :

```
static Mat Particle = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << 0, 0, 0, 0);

std::vector<Mat> pParticles;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    pParticles.push_back(Particle.clone());
}
```